# Hystrix high memory usage with over 1000 commands

Tags: hystrix

I'm seeing high memory usage when using more than a 1000 Hystrix commands in my service.

Use case:

- Service makes REST calls.
- Each REST endpoint can receive thousands of call. Need to open circuit when an endpoint is misbehaving.
- There could be thousands (upper bound 15000) such REST endpoints (each in different domain).
- There is no common group key between these REST endpoints.

I'm able to get to about 1 GB of memory usage for around 10,000 unique commands but not any lesser. Here is the setting that I'm using. As you can see I've almost shut down the latency metrics. Is there anything else that I can do to reduce the memory footprint? I'd have loved to be able to kick some old `HystrixCircuitBreaker` instances from the cache but can't see any way of doing that. In place of UUID.randomUUID() I plan to pass a context from the caller.

```
Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("BookreaderCommand"))
                    .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey("ReadBooks" + UUID.randomUUID()))
                    .andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults(HystrixThreadPoolProperties.defaultSetter()
                            .withMaxQueueSize(20))
                    .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.defaultSetter()
                            .withExecutionIsolationStrategy(HystrixCommandProperties.ExecutionIsolationStrategy.SEMAPHORE)
                            .withExecutionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests(1)
                            .withCircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds(300000)
                            .withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(1000)
                            .withCircuitBreakerEnabled(true)
                            .withCircuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold(1)
                            .withCircuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage(100)
                            .withMetricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds(1000)
                            .withMetricsRollingStatisticalWindowBuckets(1)
                            .withMetricsRollingPercentileEnabled(false) // Percentile not enabled.
                            .withMetricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds(1000)
                            .withMetricsRollingPercentileWindowBuckets(1)
                            .withMetricsHealthSnapshotIntervalInMilliseconds(1000)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is expected. Hystrix documentation suggests that circuits with more than 1000 unique CommandKey values are expected to cause high memory usage.

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.java#L212

Those looking for alternatives can look at resilience4J
https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker